# Grails : Adding data in a many-to-many relationship generate an error

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I've created a many-to-many relationship between two object in Grails 2.4 but when I try to add data in my bootstrap file, it fails and give me this error

```
Message: No signature of method: ca.ogsl.romm.observation.Behavior.addToTaxonGroup() is applicable for argument types: (ca.ogsl.romm.observation.TaxonGroup) values: [ca.ogsl.romm.observation.TaxonGroup : (unsaved)]
Possible solutions: addToTaxonGroups(java.lang.Object)
```

These are my domain class

**Behavior.groovy**

```
class Behavior {
    int id
    String code
    String nameFr
    String nameEn

    static belongsTo = TaxonGroup
    static hasMany = [taxonGroups: TaxonGroup]

    static constraints = {
        nameFr nullable: true
        nameEn nullable: true
    }
}
```

**TaxonGroup.groovy**

```
class TaxonGroup {
    int id
    String code
    String nameFr
    String nameEn

    static hasMany = [behaviors: Behavior]

    static constraints = {
        nameFr nullable: true
        nameEn nullable: true
        behaviors nullable: true
    }
}
```

Finaly, this is the code in my **BootStrap.groovy**

```
new Behavior(code: "basking")
            .addToTaxonGroup(new TaxonGroup(code:"reptiles"))
            .save()
```

I've been searching for hours and try many adding ways but nothing seems to solve this issue...

Anyone as an idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much for your time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addToXXX and removeFromXXX dynamic methods are created from the key in the `hasMany` map; this is also the name of the `Set` or `List` that Grails adds to the class for you to hold the items. Prefix with `addTo` (or `removeFrom`) and capitalize the first letter - so for `taxonGroups` it would be `addToTaxonGroups`, not `addToTaxonGroup`. Likewise for `behaviors` it'd be `addToBehaviors` and `removeFromBehaviors`.

Also, unrelated (and not a problem) - remove `behaviors nullable: true`; that doesn't have any effect. Collections (except when you first instantiate the class instance) are either empty or have one or more items, but will never be null in a persistence instance.

And delete `int id` - Grails adds a `Long id` property to the bytecode for you during compilation via an AST, and there's rarely any benefit of redundantly specifying the property since pretty much every editor/IDE/etc. expects there to be an `id` field, so it won't help with autocomplete, etc.

Comment: Well you're all right I was thinking that I should do the link with the class but that makes no sense at all if you have more than one relationship on the same object. Using the attribute name capitalized did solve my issue. Thank you for your help and for the other suggestions!!